# Cannot process definition to array for type json after updating magento 2.2.3 to 2.3.3

Tags: magento2.3.3, magento-upgrade, setup-upgrade

I am upgrading magento 2.2.3 to 2.3.3 via command line

after running this command `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
but I am getting this error:

`Cannot process definition to array for type json`

what should I do? How should I find the cause of this error?

Comment: are you using Fishpig Wordpress extension's ??

Comment: do you have somwhere in your `db_schema.xml` files a column with `xsi:type="json"` ?

Comment: @RkRathod No, I am not using Fishpeg or WordPress extensions'

Comment: You are getting this error because "data type" of any third-party extension's table's column is json.

Comment: @Marius Where should I look for this file? inside extensions folders? or Magento? or any other location?

Comment: Anywhere. Just do a search in files named `db_schema.xml` for `xsi:type="json"`

Comment: @RkRathod Yup, you are right, but I can't find it and have no idea how to find the cause of the problem as no clear error is given

Comment: export the database and search for keywords json

Comment: and also try to debuge and check which table or which column causes this issue

Comment: @Marius didn't find anything

Comment: @RkRathod ok, I am trying this

Comment: @RkRathod didn't work, nothing found, and there is no log to debug the problem